# Publishing to Location Pages using Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using Facebooks' Graph API:

I'll send GET  to `{user-id}/accounts?access_token=123CorrectToken456` which returns list of Facebook pages and access_tokens for each page that I have rights to. This allows me to GET and POST to those pages.

**But how do you access and post to a page's locations?** (see Dunkin' Donuts location pages for example)

I've tried using the `{page-id}/locations` which returns the locations and gives me read access but I can't post to those pages. ???

Comment: Are you an admin of the location page as well?

Comment: The location's `can_post` attribute is true and the same user is the one who created the pages. Have you been able to post to a location page @CBroe?

Comment: I have no such page structure available to test on right now. Anyway, if `can_post` says the viewing user can post, but the actual API result contradicts that, you should file a bug report.

Comment: You can only post as a page that you are an admin of. If the page is not returned via /me/accounts it would indicate that you are not an admin. If you are an admin of the location page and it is not returned then you should file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs.

The can_post field indicates that you can post to this page, not post as the page.

Comment: @HeyDarren Thanks. I'll get the admin rights changed and be up and running